# How to map all containing folders using volume path docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker so let me know whether I should be doing something completely different, but here goes..

I'd like to create a volume within an nginx container which maps all sites-enabled configuration files to the location on the container. The catch is, these files are scattered across multiple folders which can be named at random. But wait! I can tell you for certain that the `.conf` file will always be in a specific folder only 1 level deep (because that's how I prefer the layout to be). Here's a basic layout explaining what I mean:

```
- images/
    - nginx/
    - docker-compose.yml
- sites/
    - site_a/
        - vhost/
            site_a.conf
    - site_b/
        - vhost/
            site_b.conf
```

I have tried to do this when declaring the volumes for nginx:

```
- ../sites/*/vhost/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: mkdir /c/Users/Yates/Documents/docker/sites/*: protocol error
```

I kind of get the error, yet I can't find anything telling me how accomplish what I eventually want. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conceptional question and your concept is very fragile and will lead to issues most probably.

What you are doing wrong is:

- the configuration for the httpd server is kept inside the sites data/configuration structure or at least its nested inside
- You are trying to configure a dynamic amount of 'services' sites using a static+nested folder. You are mixing up "configuration" and data. Try to put your configuration into something like consul/etcd/zookeeper and generate configuration usint tiller ( confd/consul-template)

**If you to force it, you can:**

Way a)
Mount the volume holding the sites folder in nginx, read only ( however this volume is called )

Then you runn an entrypoint script in the nginx container, some `find` expression to traverse your "sites" folder, find any site, use the vhost folder and create a symlink from there to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

You need to also think about deletions, so pick a good namespaces for the symlinks, like `mysite.automated.conf` and before the entrypoint creates the symlinks, you run `rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*automated.conf` to flush the potentially outdated/deleted ones. You can do it the update way also, but thats for more complicated..

way b)

If you can, change the structure of sites in general, extrac all "vhosts" into one folder, lets say you will have

```
sites/vhosts/*.sites.conf
sites/data/siteA/
sites/data/siteA/
```

and then mount the volume read-only on nginx and symlink sites/vhosts to /etc/nginx/site-enabled ( the folder itself )

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can't do this.

What you could do is <s>symlink</s> copy all the .conf files into a single directory on the host and use that as your volume mount point. Or just mount the `sites/` root directory.

Comment: I believe symlinking to files outside of the mounted volume will break the volume.

Comment: @Paul - ah, makes sense. Just tested it, it won't break the volume but you can't follow the symlink. Hardlinking would probably work but that's a fairly unusual thing to do.